# Do nested transactions have any effect on locking

Tags: neo4j

```
begin tx1
    do some work
    begin tx2
      do some work
    tx2.success
    tx2.finish
tx1.success
tx1.finish
```

does **tx2.finish** actually commit or release locks?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Neo4j has the notion of **flat nested transactions**. Flat nested transactions means that all nested transactions are added to the scope of the top level transaction. So in your case `tx2` can mark the entire transaction for rollback and Neo4j will rollback both `tx1` and `tx2`. In your case only `tx1.finish` will commit the transaction.

All modifications within a Neo4j's transactions are kept in memory until commit or rollback. Locks are then obtained to do the actual flush. So in your case `tx1.finish` is when the locks are obtained.

Read [this section](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/transactions-interaction.html) of the Neo4j manual for more information.

Comment: That depends on which locks you're refering to. Write locks on nodes and relationships are acquired when modifying the nodes and relationships inside the transaction, not as late as in finish()